# Can't install from usb after messing up UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, xubuntu, uefi

I messed up my dualboot while experimenting (I still have Windows 8 installed) and now I want to:

- remove GRUB that's still lingering on my laptop,
- be able to boot from usb again,
- install Xubuntu next to Windows on separate partitions,

I need Xubuntu dual-booted with Windows on my laptop.

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode, the grub boot loader is in the protective MBR of the gpt drive. That will never be used and you should not ever boot in BIOS mode anyway which would try to load that and give an error. If you still have UEFI boot entries, you have to remove ubuntu folder from efi partition and use efibootmgr to delete UEFI entry. Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu Before doing anything make sure you have a full backup of the efi partition and the Windows partition.

Comment: No I installed in UEFI mode from the start. However I did have secure boot controle enabled when I first installed Xubuntu. But as I cannot boot any other OS than Windows I can not clear the uefi of any residue of the xubuntu install.

Comment: You still should be able to boot from USB flash drive. But you may have turned off in UEFI boot from USB. Or with secure boot it is not allowed unless you set a UEFI password which you must never forget.

Comment: I have never set an UEFI password, could you explain why I should do that?

Comment: Only if you need that to allows certain settings. Many newer UEFI seem to want that. UEFI is otherwise very limited. But some UEFI do not need password, so read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Think this article might help you out, it goes into detail on how to fix grub and remove it etc..
[Easy linux tips project](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub)

Ive added the how to from the above link below so the site rules are followed.

id suggest to anyone before installing any Linux on a partition or hard drive to try it out on a virtual machine first. if your only going to use it for your internship then id just use a VM full stop that's what i do all the time, means i can also break the OS then just reinstalling it without any hassle aswell.

> Boot problems with Windows 8 or 8.1, can often be solved in the following manner.
>
> 1. If you don't have an install DVD of Windows 8.x, then download a free evaluation copy of Windows 8.1 at Microsoft itself.
>
> If you don't have a Windows Live account, you need to create one for this. It's free, and >it's not necessary to fill out your real name.
>
> 2. Burn the iso on a DVD in the right way. That can be done in the same way as with an iso of Ubuntu.
> 3. Boot your computer from the Windows 8 DVD and select:
>      Repair your computer (down left, do NOT select "Install now") - Troubleshoot - Advanced >options - Command Prompt
> 4. Now type the following command line (note the required space between "bootrec" and "/fixmbr"):
>
> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> Press Enter.
>
> Then:
>
> bootrec /fixboot
>
> Press Enter.
>
> Then:
>
> bootrec /scanos
>
> Press Enter.
>
> Then:
>
> bootrec /rebuildbcd
>
> Press Enter. Confirm the action by typing y and press Enter again.
>
> 5. Remove the DVD and turn your computer off (press the hardware power button for five seconds).
> 6. Turn your computer on again and press the key for one-time boot changes. For Acer computers this key is usually F12, but this differs for each brand.
> 7. Select "Windows Boot Manager". After a short while you should be presented again with the (in)famous tiles of Windows 8.
> 8. If you have a dual boot computer, with Linux alongside Windows, then you might need to restore Grub, in order to make your Linux bootable again.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! In the article in the part to remove grub it says to use the windows install dvd and a few commands such as "bootrec /fixboot", "/fixmbr" "scanos"v I've tried all these things but to no avail. I have managed to boot in Windows automatically. But since I can't boot from usb I have the feeling it is due to grub, is that possible?

Comment: Honestly don't know but if you've followed those steps then i doubt it could be that as grub shouldve been removed, sounds more like a bios issue to me (UEFI) tried messing around with these settings in your bios?